# 34grid : How to create a column with 2/3 width?

Tags: css, 34grid

Using [34 Responsive Grid system](http://34grid.com/), how to create a column with two-third of full width ?

The Grid System has equal columns settings, but how can I colspan / merge 2 columns ?

```
<div class="container">
    <section class="row">
        <div class="col_1">100%</div>
    </section>
    <section class="row">
        <div class="col_2">50%</div>
        <div class="col_2">50%</div>
    </section>
    <section class="row">
        <div class="col_3">33%</div>
        <div class="col_3">33%</div>
        <div class="col_3">33%</div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it is as documented in the homepage which you should thoroughly read.

try this:

```
<section class="row">
    <div class="col_3c">66%</div>
    <div class="col_3">33%</div>
</section>
```